# How Do You Build This?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm just now getting into jquery and slowly learning it (shame, I know), and as a webdesigner I find its use to be very important.

Now I'm trying to figuire out how one would build a slider as the one shown on: http://karmalooptv.com

I have looked at the source code but due to the site being hosted on drupal, there are many unnecessary scripts and styles that are required for this slider to work that may not be required for my needs.

I don't understand how It can stretch accross the screen and cycle through the images, and when it reaches the last slide either to the left or right it'll fill it in with the first/last image and keep going.

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: Here is a tutorial that will help - http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Comment: I haven't tried anything because frankly I'm clueless, I'm not asking for the code really just for direction like Jay has done. Now that I understand how to build an infinite carousel I'm wondering how they were able to stretch the slider accross any screen size?

Comment: For that you would set you CSS for those div's to use percentages instead of pixels. You'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this jsFiddle to help you : http://jsfiddle.net/QEVqN/7/

There is the raw functionality for a slider. Let me explain what I'm doing:
1) The visible slides and the one that enters are the only ones that need animated, 
2) When we navigate left or right, align the entering slide to the correct position (right or left) and animate it with the visible ones to right or left

You don't have to animate all the slides, if there are many (maybe 100), and you get the circular effect.
Usually, you will set overflow:hidden for the div that contains all the slides, but I didn't so you can see what happens behind it. Here is with overflow:hidden http://jsfiddle.net/QEVqN/6/

Comment: thank you so much, this was the best example I could find. I'm guessing its somewhat impossible to have the width infinite?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. You can't set infinite width, and I can't imagine what you need it for.

Comment: You can set the width of the elements using percentages and it would adapt to any display

Comment: I'm trying to figuire out how the jquery code you have works, thank you though I believe I understand how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques you need:

1. First, a div with overflow-hidden to be like a picture frame that hides everything outside of it.
2. Second, a longer div that contains all your images side by side.  This div will be inside your overflow-hidden div and be the same height.
3. Your content div will just move its x location backwards until it gets to the last slide.
4. Then, when you get to the last slide, you swap the first and last and immediately move the content div so that the last slide is showing again.  This is how you get the continuous effect.

All the animations in #3 are gradual, so you get the scrolling effect.  The change in #4 is instantaneous, so the user will not know.

Comment: Thank You Jonathan for Breaking It Down. I'll start experimenting with this technique and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the slideshows mentioned here:
http://slodive.com/freebies/best-jquery-slideshow-gallery-plugins/

This is also a nice one:
http://slidesjs.com/

Most jQuery plugins allow you to customize the cycling behavior, but they'll all have different syntax for this.

In the example you posted, they were able to stretch the image across the screen by setting the width (990px) and height (554px) CSS properties for the  elements.

Comment: ohh so they basically have an infinite number of slides if you have as the screen size gets larger?

Comment: or should I say grow with the screen size?

Comment: If you want the image and slider to grow with the screen, you can set the image width to 100% as gabitzish suggested (you may also have to set this width on parent elements for the image, depending on what your markup and CSS look like)